# Assitance with "breathing" font size (increasing and decreasing using coroutines)

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, coroutine

I'm trying to make the font of my 'Start Game' button "breath", increasing and decreasing in size using Coroutines.

Font size starts with 2.0, onStart it increases to 2.20 (progresively by +0.01 till it reaches 2.20) and then drops back to 2.0 (progresively by -0.01 till it reaches 2.0) and then repeat.

My code works for the first part perfectly where it increase all the way to 2.20 but for some reason it is not decreasing back to 2.0 from 2.20. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
public class Font_Breathing : MonoBehaviour {

public TMP_Text startGame;
private float change = 0.01f;
private float delay = 0.0f;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(IncreaseFont());
}

void Update()
{

}

IEnumerator IncreaseFont()
{

    while (startGame.fontSize >= 2.0f)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        startGame.fontSize += change;

        if (startGame.fontSize >= 2.20f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DecreaseFont());
        }
    }

}

IEnumerator DecreaseFont()
{
    while (startGame.fontSize >= 2.20f)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        startGame.fontSize -= change;

        if (startGame.fontSize <= 2.0f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(IncreaseFont());
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Coroutine seems a bit overkill for this task (a simple cycler).  Why not try something simpler?

eg:

```
public class Breathe : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI Text;

    public float Size1;
    public float Size2;

    public AnimationCurve Ease;
    public float Speed;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var minSize = Mathf.Min(Size1, Size2);
        var totalOffset = Mathf.Abs(Size1 - Size2);

        var factor = Ease.Evaluate(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * Speed, 1));

        Text.fontSize = minSize + totalOffset * factor;
    }
}
```

---

To answer your coroutine question specifically,  I can't seem to find a direct fault with it, but I would make some changes to rule out possibilities.

You had:

```
IEnumerator IncreaseFont() {

    // !!! This check looks like a copy-paste error from your DecreaseFont()
    //     Also, do not check for equality otherwise you will go PAST your cut-off
    while (startGame.fontSize >= 2.0f) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        startGame.fontSize += change;

        //  !!! This check is redundant -> Move it outside the loop
        if (startGame.fontSize >= 2.20f) {
            StartCoroutine(DecreaseFont());
        }
    }
}
```

I would make it:

```
IEnumerator IncreaseFont() {

    while (startGame.fontSize < 2.20f) {
        // yielding for null just waits for next frame, gives smoother animation
        yield return null; 

        startGame.fontSize += change;
    }

    // If you reach this point, the while loop has exited and can assumed that fontSize >= 2.2f
    StartCoroutine(DecreaseFont());
}
```

Comment: I tried this method and it works but its very snappy i think that i'm adjusting the variables incorrectly. Please correct me if i'm wrong: Size1 is the minimum size of the font so in my case i would use 2. Size2 is the maximum so i'd put 2.20 since we're using Mathf which goes from 0-1 we're reseting it to 2-2.20? and then multiplying it by speed.

Comment: It doesn't matter which Size is bigger as the ```minSize``` and ```totalOffset``` works out which is smaller and what the difference is.  If the animation is too fast, use smaller values for Speed.  If you want smoother transition from Increase to Decrease, change the Ease (usually you would use the S-curve, aka 'ease-in-out').

Comment: So, ```Size1 = 2.0f``` and ```Size2 = 2.2f``` to suit your needs.  Then ```Speed = 1f``` will go from smallest to largest in one second (and back in one more second).   ```Speed = 2f``` will go from smallest to largest in one-half a second.

Comment: (Think of ```Speed``` as "half-cycles per second")

Comment: it worked just how i wanted! I was getting the ease graph wrong and it made it snappy. I must look into ease and math.f to learn how to implement them like you just did. Thank you. On a side note, i know that the coroutines might've been the wrong approach that i took initially, but by anychance do you see what i was doing wrong with my code initially? For educations sake.

Comment: @RamKillnani Added to answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic was off and so you were always increasing your font try the below and let me know how you go.

Also I believe you need to manually tell a Coroutine to stop otherwise it will run endlessly so look into running `StopCoroutine`

```
IEnumerator IncreaseFont()
{

  while (startGame.fontSize < 2.20f)
  {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    startGame.fontSize += change;

    if (startGame.fontSize >= 2.20f)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DecreaseFont());
        StopCoroutine(IncreaseFont());
    }
  }
}


IEnumerator DecreaseFont()
{
  while (startGame.fontSize > 2.0f)
  {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    startGame.fontSize -= change;

    if (startGame.fontSize <= 2.0f)
    {
        StartCoroutine(IncreaseFont());
        StopCoroutine(DecreaseFont());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for commenting! I tried making the changes with your code but it still stops after increasing and remains at 2.20 and doesn't begin to decrease.

Comment: Was that including the edit i made regarding `stopCoroutine()` ??? @RamKillnani

Comment: Yes i added that before commenting.

Comment: Hmmmm, sorry this didn't solve your issue, the last thing i'll suggest is to add some debugs to make sure you are entering the functions as expected that could help you narrow down the issue

Comment: No worries! I'll try to debug a little bit and see what i can do. Thank you for trying :)

Comment: The ```StopCoroutine``` isn't working because you're creating a new ```IEnumerator``` with the call to ```IncreaseFount()``` instead of providing a reference to the originally created coroutine.